# How to use the multiplication symbol

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript code and I am blanking out right now. I can't remember how to use the multiplication symbol "X". This code here is an example, but is using the addition symbol. Can anyone show me how to replace the addition symbol with the multiplication symbol? I know it's probably a real easy fix.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function sum()
      {

         var num1 = document.myform.number1.value;
         var num2 = document.myform.number2.value;
         var sum = parseInt(num1) * parseInt(num2);
         document.getElementById('add').value = sum;
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <form name="myform">
      <input type="text" name="number1" value=""/> + 
      <input type="text" name="number2" value=""/>
      <input type="button" name="button" Value="=" onClick="sum()"/>
      <input type="text" id="add" name="result" value=""/>
    </form>
```

Comment: you mean `+` --> `&times;`?

Comment: Have you got access to the HTML? than just _replace the characters_ if not, wrap the plus in a block element (`<span id='operand'>+</span>` and use the id to change/get it's contents. Also, `parseInt` should always be used with the radix specified explicitly: `parseInt(foo, 10)` [refer to MDN why](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: This is obviously an extension of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254526/converting-from-addition-to-multiplication). I don't know what you're up to, but if this is your way of learning a programming language, it's a terrible approach.

Comment: ...and if you're trying to have StackOverflow rewrite your code for you one question at a time, please stop.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign

Comment: @am not i am, I don't know what you are talking about, but you seem to be a little grump aren't you. What do you care anyways? Do you have anything good going in your life? Here's some advice, get off the computer and get a life.

Comment: --that other question is clearly from someone else by the way. Pay closer attention.

Comment: @user2327399: Yep, you're just about as pathetic as I assumed. Nope, you just switched accounts.

Comment: @am not i am gay, do you always offer just great advice? You must be one of those "I told you so" people who know everything huh? Yeah, I miss beating you guys up...

Comment: I do offer great advice, and I help people worth helping. And no, you've never been in a fight... at least not one that you didn't crawl away from.

Comment: @am not i am, listen guy I don't know what stirred your day but I didn't come here to get into arguments with anyone. Hope your day is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the `+` with `&times;`:

```
<input type="text" name="number1" value=""/> &times;
```

Comment: Or with the character `×` directly. And, while you're about it, rename the function from `sum()` to `multiply()` to prevent confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that's what I needed. Sometimes I just completely forget the little things.

Comment: you cannot forget something you don't know.

Answer (score 1):

from http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html

the character entity is `&times;` === ×